# Should an automated build process commit changes to version control?

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, build-automation

I have often seen automated build processes, including Continuous Integration builds, commit changes made to source files during the build back into the version control repository that the source originated from*. Auto-incrementing version numbers is a common scenario where this is done but there are others.

My intuition is that this is a bad idea as it can litter the repository history with build-related commits and the build process needs to prevent accidentally re-triggering itself. However I don't have any concrete evidence that committing changes during a build is best avoided.

Can anyone cite references discussing the pros and cons of commit changes to version control during an automated build?

*Committing changes to a separate artifact repository is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

> Auto-incrementing version numbers

That is a **metadata**, and putting metadata in (versioned) data is "evil": for the pros and cons, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645424/6309).

[Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) includes the **build automation**, which is about being able to **reproduce** a build from a *fixed* set of versioned data.
If you change anything back in that same set, you sort of defeat its purpose.

Comment: I considered the issue of being able to reproduce a build but if a build run against Version N commits a change back to source control and creates Version N+1 then repeating the build against Version N again will be ignorant of N+1 and shouldn't change the output.

Comment: @JasonStangroome: but it will create uselessly version N+1 over and over again. Just don't do it. It serves no useful purpose. CI is about *reading and building, no writing anything.